# Why SDP not match when a msrp invite coming to the freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

When i make a call that from 1016 to 1015 ,and my voip phone support msrp,so i want to send text-message form one leg to the other. I find that FreeSwitch handle the incoming message as a normal sip invite and will generate a session (also a channel)instance for the invite i make.The channel state is set to CS_NEW,then it into the sofia state callback to handle the different stage of sip procedure.When the sdp is parsed ,the freeswitch tell me the sdp is not match,so the session is turn off and the channel is hungup.I don't know how to configuration(if the freeswitch support msrp),or how to make this right.Thank you very much if you can give me more infomation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that you might be running an older code base that doesn't have MSRP support it was only recently added to FreeSWITCH in JIRA FS-3748 (DEC-2011).  If you're running the latest code then the proper course of action would be to reopen FS-3748 (http://jira.freeswitch.org/browse/FS-3748) and report your findings on the JIRA and seek a possible fix.

StackOverflow isn't the proper location to report bugs.

Thanks,
Brian West
FreeSWITCH.org

Comment: Yes,i user the fs-1.0.6.I will download the latest code and test it.Thank you very much.